I got this code from a course lecture: I'm using Rstudio and R together. "rank" is giving an obviously wrong answer
Here is what my Rstudio tells me:
> x <- c(31, 4, 15, 92, 65)
> x
[1] 31  4 15 92 65
> rank(x)    # returns ranks (smallest to largest)
[1] 3 1 2 5 4


The obviously correct answer is "[1] 2 3 1 5 4"

How can something so simple and obvious come out wrong?
